# Remote Attribute Validation not working in ASP MVC 4

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, remote-validation

I have been working with MVC 3 and the [Remote(action,controller)] seems to work perfect, trying to do the same in MVC 4 results in a never called function.

A quick google or stackoverflow search will give you lots of the same fails in MVC4.

What I did was:

Model:

```
[Remote("CheckIt", "Default1", ErrorMessage = "It happens")]
public virtual string City { get; set; }
```

In Default1 Controller:

```
public JsonResult CheckIt(string city)
{
    return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you have an online "demo" where it's possible to inspect the data going back and forth/eventual javascript exceptions, etc.?

Comment: Do you have client side validation enabled?

Comment: @Alxandr No, sorry I do not, but, I can check and reply back, do you mean something like FireBug?

Comment: @Moeri Yes, I think in MVC3 it was turned off, but at least in MVC4, I always see it turned ON by default.

Comment: Yes, something like that, and other things. But I cannot efficiently explain all the things I would check... But if you can, check for script errors + request data.

Comment: Answer the following: 

- Do you have the jqueryval bundle rendered on the page? Check if jquery.validate.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js is present

- Are there data-... attributes on your input element that contain validation properties?

- When you check the network tab in Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools, do you see a request being launched when you enter something in the input field (and leave it by pressing 'tab' or clicking elsewhere)

- If so, does that request succeed or does it give any errors?